# Django : add class to every x'th element

Tags: django, django-templates

Lets say I have an object

```
foo =[ob1, obj2, obj3 ... obj100 ...]
```

Now I would like to loop through them in my template but in groups of 5,

So there will be 5 objects per "row". and in each row I would like to add a class to the first and last one in that row.

Is there a clean why of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [cycle](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle) tag:

```
<td class="{% cycle 'first' '' '' '' 'last' %}">
</td>
```

or:

```
<td{% cycle ' class="first"' '' '' '' ' class="last"' %}">
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's already an even and uneven adding template filter in django itself. Look at it and create your own custom filter..

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

```
    register = template.Library()

    @register.filter
    def count_each_5th_object(value, arg):
        counter = 0
        for object in value:
            counter += 1
            if counter % arg etcetera...
```

But if you are trying to achieve this result purely for styling reasons I recommend using css only... look into: first-child, nth-child(5n+5) and last-child